# GORM: Define multiple columns with same foreign key

Tags: go, foreign-keys, go-gorm

I am creating a Golang MySQL project where I am using GORM. I have a table called accounts with fields

```
    ID        uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment;not_null"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Company   string    `json:"company"`
    GSTIN     string    `json:"gstin"`
    AccountNo string    `json:"accountNo" gorm:"unique"`
    IFSC      string    `json:"ifsc"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
```

Now I want to make a table called transactions with fields

```
    ID            uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment;not_null"`
    Amount        float64   `json:"amount"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
    Date          time.Time `json:"Date"`
    PaymentMode   string    `json:"paymentMode"`
    SourceId      uint      `json:"source"`   ------>>>>> Want this to be AccountID foreign key
    UTR           string    `json:"utr" gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    DestinationId uint      `json:"to"`       ------>>>>> Want this to be AccountID foreign key
    Account       Account
```

I cant figure out how to define this in go gorm? Can I have two fields with with foreign key to same column of another table? How to do this?

Comment: What two fields would have a foreign key to the accounts table? I can only see one account reference there at the moment.

Comment: @Shadow I want the SourceId and DestinationId to be linked to AccountsId.

Comment: And what prevents you from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it using this. Thanks!

```
    type Debit struct {
    ID                 uint      `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment;not_null"`
    Amount             float64   `json:"amount"`
    CreatedAt          time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt          time.Time `json:"updatedAt"`
    PaymentMode        string    `json:"paymentMode"`
    SourceId           uint      `json:"sourceId"`
    UTR                string    `json:"utr" gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    DestinationId      uint      `json:"destinationId"`
    SourceAccount      Account   `gorm:"foreignKey:SourceId"`
    DestinationAccount Account   `gorm:"foreignKey:DestinationId"`
}
```